Count repeating character dynamically
This is a follow-up question.  I have these 2 column with repeating characters: 'aaaaaa' 'bbbb'  'cccdef'.
Result:
aaaaaa: 6
bbbb: 4
cccdef: 3

I need to dynamically find how many times the character is repeated based on the character position 1 from left.
Only applies if the max length of the string is less than 10.

From this suggested expression, how do I modify it to accomplish this.
SELECT LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, ',', '')) FROM TableName

Tried the code below and got an error.
LENGTH(Client_Comment1_CPS_OTHR) - (LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(Client_Comment1_CPS_OTHR, (CONCAT("'",   LEFT(Client_Comment1_CPS_OTHR,1),"'"), '')) as repeatedchar_cnt


As far as I understand your question, you need to count the repetitions of the first character. Here is the sql for this:
WITH table1 AS (
 SELECT col
 FROM UNNEST([
   'aaaaaa',
   'bbbb',
   'cccdef',
   'abc',
   'aabcdef',
   'aaaaaaaaaaa' -- This one has length >= 10 and will be excluded
 ]) AS col
)

SELECT 
  col,  
  SUBSTR(col, 1, 1) first_character,
  CONCAT('^', REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(col, 1, 1), r'([^\w])', r'\\\1'), '+') regex,
  LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT(col, CONCAT('^', REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(col, 1, 1), r'([^\w])', r'\\\1'), '+'))) AS repeat_count
FROM table1
WHERE
 LENGTH(col) < 10;




col
first_character
regex
repeat_count




aaaaaa
a
^a+
6


bbbb
b
^b+
4


cccdef
c
^c+
3


abc
a
^a+
1


aabcdef
a
^a+
2



